# Select Top 5 values from table with ORDERBY and GROUPBY functions not working fine

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

My query is as below

```
Cursor c=mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT name, MAX(user_score) AS max_score  
     FROM "+TableName+"
     WHERE user_score IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY name 
     ORDER BY max_score
     DESC LIMIT 5",
     null);
```

i want to show only the top five of the scorers. All the other things in my code are working fine and if run simple Select * from tablename it working fine and give the results.

Help me and give me the solution where i am wronge and is there any syntex problem in sqllite or anything else ?
Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a space between the table name and `WHERE`, otherwise the syntax looks correct.

Comment: after given the space it is not working.No record is shown there

Comment: @NareshSharma When I create a test table and run the query manually it works and gives the correct results, both on Linux and Android. Since you're not showing your table structure or what TableName is set to it's hard to see why you're not getting results, could you echo out the actual string after it's built and try running it manually?

Comment: thanks sir my problem is now solved and i looked carefully again all the things and it helped me. thanks for your response and hpoe the same things in the future as well.